# Byte arrays through C#,Python and T-SQL

Tags: c#, python, t-sql, hash

**Main Question :**

I need to translate python byte array to T-SQL byte array, is there any way of doing so?

**Explanation:**

I want to achive this:

1. Script (Python) sends Http Get to server with string
2. Server API (C#) returns hash of string as byte[]
3. Hash of the string is copy pasted via human into the query to database (T-SQL)

Hash on the server is generated by SHA256 algorithm (UTF-8 encoding), then copied into byte array and returned.
Python gets a hash using urllib.request it is returned to the end user who will copy it to query.
I already got algorithms for hashing and getting hash from server (posted at the end).

**Example :**

From script I send "password" as string to be hashed, on server side hash looks like this:

> 94 136 72 152 218 40 4 113 81 208 229 111 141 198 41 39 115 96 61 13 106 171 189 214 42 17 239 114 29 21 66 216

In python my output is

> "XohImNooBHFR0OVvjcYpJ3NgPQ1qq73WKhHvch0VQtg="

But if we put byte array from server to T-SQL directly it looks like this :

> 0x5E884898DA28047151D0E56F8DC6292773603D0D6AABBDD62A11EF721D1542D8

**Code snippets:**

Please ignore possible exceptions and such - those are simplified methods.

Hashing method ( C# )

```
using (var alg = SHA256.Create())
{ 
    return alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
}
```

Hash returning method (C#)

```
[HttpGet,ResponseType(typeof(byte[]))]
public IHttpActionResult GetPasswordHash(string toHash)
{
    var hashed = password.Hash();
    return Ok(hashed);
}
```

Python script

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
api = "http://localhost:12302/api/" 
password = input("Put password\t") 
url = api+"/Utils/Hash?toHash=%s" % password
url = urllib.request.Request(url)
responseData = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(responseData.read())
```

**EDIT** :

Human's query is going to be :

```
insert into table(user_password) 
values(HERECOMESPASSWORD)
```

so copy paste of "XohImNooBHFR0OVvjcYpJ3NgPQ1qq73WKhHvch0VQtg=" to HERECOMESPASSWORD won't do the trick.

Comment: The python result is base64 encoded and the SQL example is hexadecimal which is how SQL will display it when queried but that is just a representation of the binary data in the field. Those two values may be equivalent, I didn't check, but you probably don't have a problem at all.

Comment: Right, you would have to bas64 DECODE that back to byte array and do one of two things: Convert that back to a hex formatted string (pain), or better, add a SqlParameter of type binary to a SqlCommand and assign the byte array directly to its value.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you very much, I misunderstood your first comment. You were 100% right, it is enoguh to convert from base64 to hex. 
Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark is as such.
How did you know that this result is base64 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from Python is a Base64 encoded representation of a byte array. I know this because, for one, it is easy to recognize after you have some experience with it. And two, because HTTP is a text protocol so whatever data you send must be somehow encoded textually.

So you must take that value and convert it back to a byte array in C#. Then you can re-encode it for SQL as hexadecimal.

But I want to caution you on deciding not to use `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameters`. What if the user instead pasted the password and something like:

```
); UPDATE [table] SET [user_password] = '..whatever..'
```

You would have a sql injection vulnerability.